# Selecting/Inserting data between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I think there are something wrong with my structure. I have 3 tables in the database. I want to show all the supply in a **specific division**. I did some trial and errors but I can't insert another supply in the same **plan id**. I wanted to add more supplies in one of specific division / specific plan id.Here's my query to select the supplies.

```
SELECT
division.acronym,
supply.`name`,
supply.unit,
supply.supply_id,
supply.price,
supply.estimated_budget,
supply.quantity
FROM
division
INNER JOIN plan ON plan.plan_id = division.division_id
INNER JOIN supply ON supply.supply_id = plan.plan_id
```

The table is only available at documentation. So, I insert my ERD diagram as an image.

[ERD edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pqK3.png)

Comment: Are you trying to _retrieve_ data from your tables, or _insert_ new data?

Comment: Your query looks al right, but I don't see any `insert`; Inserting might fail due to primary key violations?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Both. I'm trying to insert and after retrieve the data. Im still learning sql. I came with this problem.

Comment: @StephanLechner, at this moment I manually insert the data. I think theres a problem with my table structure.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put `division_id` and `supply_id` to plan table as *FOREIGN KEYS* to join all three tables.

Then your query should look like:

```sql
division
INNER JOIN plan ON plan.division_id=division.division_id
INNER JOIN supply ON supply.supply_id=plan.supply_id
```